# Unable to to install Heimdall on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: software-installation, heimdall

```
The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/modycz/heimdall/ubuntu bionic Release'
does not have a Release file.
```

Just started two weeks ago on Ubuntu. real novice!

Answer (score 5):

#### Answer to your question

According to [this page on Launchpad](http://ppa.launchpad.net/modycz/heimdall/ubuntu/dists/), the newest versions of this PPA are *devel* and *utopic*, dated August 2014. Your current distro (`bionic`) is therefore too young to be found in this PPA.

#### Answer to your problem

Heimdall is in Ubuntu 18.04, only it's not called `heimdall` but `heimdall-flash`:

```
$ apt search heimdall
Sorting... Done
Full Text Search... Done
heimdall-flash/bionic 1.4.1-2 amd64
  tool for flashing firmware on Samsung Galaxy S devices

heimdall-flash-frontend/bionic 1.4.1-2 amd64
  tool for flashing firmware on Samsung Galaxy S devices - Qt GUI
```

So you can install it with

```
sudo apt install heimdall-flash
```